# F# Please explain how the result is calculated (List.fold (+) (-))

Tags: f#

The result is 4. But I do not understand why. Also to where is the 1 fed into? I thought it is being fed into ((-) 2) as the second parameter but its not. Please explain what is happening step by step.

```
1 |> List.fold (fun x y -> (+) (x y)) ((-) 2) [3;4]
```

Comment: If its written like `List.fold applyAdd twoMinusN [3;4] 1`, where `let applyAdd x y a = x y + a` and `let twoMinusN n = 2 - n`, does that help?

Comment: List.fold applyAdd twoMinusN [3;4] 1 <<< This 1 at the end???? How? fold takes only 3 parametres but you used 4. what is this 1 at the end?

Comment: See the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Given is the expression in the question:

```
1 |> List.fold (fun x y -> (+) (x y)) ((-) 2) [3;4]
```

To make things a bit simpler, lets throw away the `1 |>` part for the moment and focus on the fold.

`List.fold a ??? [2;3;4;5]` is turned into `(a (a (a (a ??? 2) 3) 4) 5`. Since we need something to start with, we'd need
to supply something for `???`. This is the initial state. So for example `List.fold a 1 [2;3;4;5]` is turned
into `(a (a (a (a 1 2) 3) 4) 5`. Note that this doesn't have anything to do with the `1` we threw away earlier.

So to translate this to `List.fold (fun x y -> (+) (x y)) ((-) 2) [3;4]` its easier to replace the folder (first parameter)
as with something named. The same goes for the second parameter, the initial state. We'd end up with:

```
let applyAdd x y a = x y + a
let twoMinusN n = 2 - n
List.fold applyAdd twoMinusN [3;4]
```

If we expand the last expression like we did before, we'd end up with `(applyAdd (applyAdd twoMinusN 3) 4)`.

Reducing it down further (I hope I brace this the right way):

```
(applyAdd (applyAdd twoMinusN 3) 4)
(applyAdd (applyAdd (fun n -> 2 - n) 3) 4)
(applyAdd ((fun x y a -> x y + a) (fun n -> 2 - n) 3) 4)
(applyAdd (fun a -> (fun n -> 2 - n) 3 + a) 4)
(applyAdd (fun a -> (-1) + a) 4)
((fun x y a -> x y + a) (fun a -> (-1) + a) 4)
(fun a -> (-1) + 4 + a)
(fun a -> 3 + a)
```

Isn't that strange? Say we started with `List.fold (+) 1 [2;3;4;5]` we'd end up with:

```
((+) ((+) ((+) ((+) 1 2) 3) 4) 5
  (* or, if that's easier to read: *)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
```

which is `15`. All we're left with is a function now, and not a single value. That's where the `1 |>` part comes into play:

```
1 |> (fun a -> 3 + a)
(fun a -> 3 + a) 1
3 + 1
4
```

Comment: So let me see if I understood this, fold returns a state & since in this example the state is a function, it returns a function. Now we pass 1 into the function. Also first pass is `(+) ( (-) 2 3 ) = (+) -1 `  and second pass is then  `(+) -1 4 = 3` & now `1 |> (+) 3 = 4` **Is that correct?**